# SharePoint 2013 Prerequisite installer keeps launching automatically after installation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, installation, prerequisites

After I deployed SharePoint 2013 on multiple servers using offline prerequisite installer, after each server restart, it starts again, and the error message says

> it cannot find the path because installation media is not mounted
>   anymore.

I found the startup task with the name:

```
"SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

but even I deleted it on every server, every time server is restarted, the task is created again.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs because of restarting the server will result in ejecting any mounted ISO file. Thence, the system cannot find the drive specified.

So try to do the following

- Mount the SharePoint media
- Run CMD as administrator
- Navigate to the drive that ISO image has been mounted and run the following command :

> `I:\>prerequisiteInstaller.exe /continue`

For more detail check [Continue prerequisiteInstaller.exe after server restart.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/05/continue-prerequisiteinstaller-exe-after-server-restart/)

Comment: I was having this issue long after successful installation of SharePoint that at each login it was trying to find installation media again and again. I followed the above given instructions and then properly dismounted media and this issue was resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear, it's helped you :)